# How to check duplicate numbers and print out the read input numbers in the same order that they were read (excluding all duplicates.)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, user-input

I'm trying to write a code. There I'll get max 1000 (int)inputs from an user (it has to be array[1000]) and it'll print out the ints in the same order as they were written.

Reading can be stopped by ctrl+z if the user wants that. The program will not write out duplicate numbers.

Example;

Input:  45 77 -22 3 45 0 21 -1 3
Output: 45 77 -22 3 0 21 -1

So far I've coded(within 2 days):

```
static int i = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[1000];
    int[] arrayCopy = new int[1000];

    int k=0,j=0;

    System.out.println("enter your integer numbers");
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();


        for(j =0 ; j< array.length; j++)
        {
            arrayCopy[j] = array[j];

        }


        for( k =1; k<arrayCopy.length; k++)
        {
            int aV = arrayCopy[k];

        }
        i++;

    }

    input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HashMap to keep track of numbers already seen. Only add to your output string if it is a new number. You can modify your code with the following:

```
int[] array = new int[1000];
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int index = 0;
while(input.hasNext()) {
    array[index] = input.nextInt();
    index++;
}

HashMap<Integer, Boolean> seenNumbers = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    int value = array[i];
    if (!seenNumbers.containsKey(value)) {
        result += " " + value;
        seenNumbers.put(value, true);
    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Hi agin @dharms i'd like to learn what those code do, if i'm not bothering you(could you please explain);                              if (!seenNumbers.containsKey(value)) {
        result += " " + value;
        seenNumbers.put(value, true);
    }                                                                                                           and why did you use hashmap instead of hashset?                     Thank you

Comment: That is checking whether the current `int` is already in the Map and only printing if it is not. You could use either a HashMap or HashSet to accomplish this. A HashSet actually implements a HashMap behind the scenes so you are using a Map regardless of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is for me  to use LinkedHashSet - will not allow duplicates and preserves insertion order

```
Set <Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(1000);
while (input.hasNext()) {
int next = input.nextInt();
set.add(next);
}
input.close();
for (Integer number : set) {
System.out.print(number+" ");}
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

Provided you can **resolve a sort order**, and use arrays:

Below pseudocode and data. It's written as arrays, but you can ofc always loop where required. I also write the data without commas, as that's what my language [Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com) outputs ;-), but the data below are simply 9-element 1-dimensional arrays. The result seems to hold 7 elements.

You have

```
A = 45 77 -22 3 45 0 21 -1 3
```

Resolve the ascending sort order for A:

```
order = 3 8 6 4 9 7 1 5 2 // A[3] is smallest, then A[8], A[6], etc.
```

Write:

```
B = A[order] // B now holds: -22 -1 0 3 3 21 45 45 77
```

Loop through all but first element of B, check if next element is same as current. Write the result to C, which is a same-length vector of zeroes, however first element of C must be 1:

```
C = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
s = 2
:While (s <= [length of C])
    C[s] = (B[s-1] == B[s]) // C[s] is 0 or 1
    s += 1
:End
```

Now C holds:

```
1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Create an empty variable D (or just copy from A or B - you will overwrite it):

```
D = A
```

Assign the elements of D as follows:

```
D[order] = C // D now holds: 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Take only D elements of A (you pick elements of A and append them to a Result, which is initially empty - ie. has zero length):

```
s = 1
:While (s <= [lenght of A])
    :if D[s] // Means: If (D[s] == 1)
        [append A[s] to Result]
        s += 1
    :End
:End
```

Result now contains

```
45 77 -22 3 0 21 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Set instead of array. Set wont add duplicates.

Comment: hashset does not preserve order of insertion